# general formula for sampling probability of statistic

Tags: probability, statistics

assume we have a probability distribution
$$p(x\mid\mu)$$
and assume we draw times from this distribution independently, then the probability distribution of receiving $x$ for the first and $y$ for the second is
$$p(x,y\mid\mu)=p(x\mid\mu)p(y\mid\mu)$$

however, say we want to generate a statistic from $x,y$, is there then  a general formula for  the probability distribution of that statistic?

say the statistic is the mean $(x+y)/2$, what would be the formula for the sampling probability distribution of the mean given any arbitrary original sampling distribution?

Comment: In most cases, two points will not tell you much for practical purposes. You could get very rough estimates of population mean and SD. If you know the type of distribution (say normal or exponential) that might help a little. If you have a particular application in mind, a further explanation of it might help someone to give a better answer.

Comment: I am talking about the probability distribution of those two samples, not the actual values themselves. That is, we haven't actually drawn to samples, we've just defined a probability distribution for those two samples. This should by clear from my notation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general formula for the distribution of the sum of two observations
(or the mean of two observations) from the same distribution. However, there are useful facts for *particular* distributions.

For example, here are a few of many relationships for *particular* families
of distributions.

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent observations from 
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu,\sigma),$ then
$X_1 + X_2 \sim \mathsf{Norm}(2\mu, \sqrt{2}\sigma).$

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent observations from 
$\mathsf{Exp}(rate=\lambda),$ then
$X_1 + X_2 \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(shape=2, rate=\lambda).$

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent observations from 
$\mathsf{Binom}(n,\theta),$ then
$X_1 + X_2 \sim \mathsf{Binom}(2n, \theta).$

More generally, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are observations from distributions
with means $\mu_1 = E(X_1)$ and $\mu_2 = E(X_2),$ respectively, then
$E(X_1 + X_2) = \mu_1 + \mu_2.$
And if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are *independent* observations from distributions
with means $\sigma_1^2 = V(X_1)$ and $\sigma_2^2 = V(X_2),$ respectively, then
$V(X_1 + X_2) = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2.$

If $X_1$ is from a distribution with moment generating function $m_1(t)$ and
$X_2$ is from a distribution with moment generating function $m_2(t),$ then
the distribution of $X_1 + X_2$ has moment generating function 
$m_1(t)m_2(t).$ Also, there are *convolution* formulas for the PDFs of
of continuous and discrete random variables.